# SQLCODE=-911, SQLSTATE=40001, SQLERRMC=68

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, db2, deadlock

The following is my method to update a row of records:

```
@Override
public void updateCurrentStatus(Long paymentHistoryId, String currentStatus) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( );
    sb.append( "update PaymentHistory SET " );
    sb.append( " currentStatus = :currentStatus ," );
    sb.append( " MODIFIEDDATETIME = CURRENT TIMESTAMP " );
    sb.append( "where paymentHistoryId = :paymentHistoryId " );

    final Query updateQuery = getSession( ).createSQLQuery( sb.toString( ) );
    updateQuery.setString( "currentStatus", currentStatus );
    updateQuery.setLong( "paymentHistoryId", paymentHistoryId );
    updateQuery.executeUpdate( );
}
```

`PaymentHistory` is an entity and `paymentHistoryId` is the `primary key`.

Thus, I believe my method will only update just **ONE** record of `PaymentHistory` table.

This process working fine so far. But yesterday I am hitting `LockAcquisitionException`. The error log will be as follow:

```
2018-01-16 19:56:15.379 [WebContainer : 657] ERROR c.c.i.c.a.a.ui.PaymentTrxAuthAction - [user1] - Encounter RuntimeException
org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1190) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate(SQLQueryImpl.java:357) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
```

I am not understand why I hitting `could not execute native bulk manipulation query` Since I am only updating 1 row of records. I believe `could not execute native bulk manipulation query` is only happen when I update a bulk of records.

For `org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException`, I didnt see any request or thread that pulling this row of record or update this row of record. I believe `LockAcquisitionException` will only happen when the record is being update by another hibernate session, and I am still proceed to update it. But in my case, its not.

Any ideas why I getting this error?

```
Here is the log from DBA:

    2018-01-17-12.32.11.071146+480 E341051933A666       LEVEL: Error
PID     : 9699328              TID : 19792          PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000           DB   : SDB   
HOSTNAME: dbhm01.com
EDUID   : 19792                EDUNAME: db2hadrp.0.1 (SDB) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, High Availability Disaster Recovery, hdrEduAcceptEvent, probe:20200
MESSAGE : Did not receive anything through HADR connection for the duration of 
          HADR_TIMEOUT. Closing connection.
DATA #1 : String, 30 bytes
hdrCurrentTime/hdrLastRecvTime
DATA #2 : unsigned integer, 4 bytes
1516163531
DATA #3 : unsigned integer, 4 bytes
1516163410
```

I do some study on this, but still not 100% understand on it. I am suspect the issue is cause by the network between application and database, or the database server is not stable. Any ideas?

Or any info I can get from this db log?

Comment: Is the application multi-threaded? Do you sequence reads and updates on multiple threads correctly?

Comment: Hi @JimGarrison , The application is multi-threaded. But the process is running in `SyncTask` instead of `AsyncTask`, thus it is run step by step. Hence, the thread Id is always the same for same process, [WebContainer : 657] .

Comment: Have you checked if the Db2 server has recorded a locking event (such as a timeout) in its diagnostics?  If the symptom is reproducible, it should be simple to diagnose a locking conflict at the database layer.

Comment: @mao, the symptom is not reproducible, it only happen 1 times so far. As my experience, I will only hit this error when I update multiple rows and many thread accessing the same row. However, this case is different and I spend long time on it still cant see the root cause.

Comment: Ask your DBA for assistance to determine if there is a lock conflict at database level. Depending on your Db2-server operating-system there are easy ways to discover this. Update your question with details of the Db2-server version and operating-system on which the Db2-server is running.  A possible scenario is one thread not committing.

Comment: Hi @mao, I get the db2diag.log from DBA, in the same time, there is some error log, I already put in my question together. I try to study on it, and I suspect that there is the network issue between the database with application, or the db server is not stable and cause this?

Comment: Your HADR error is unlikely to be related to a lock conflict, and that HADR-congestion is a matter for your DBA. Don't mix  different symptoms in one thread.

Comment: Sorry @mao, I put int the wrong log. Now I edit it and put in the correct one. Can help again?

Comment: Does not matter. HADR errors are a matter for the DBA and not for you. They are also not related to your original symptom.

Comment: At first I have a concept that because of HADR have some error, causing dabtase can not response back to application accodingly, and hence my application hit time out because waiting too long. This concept totally wrong?

Comment: Yes that is possible, depending on the HADR sync-mode used. But I would expect the DBA to resolve such matters by correct configuration. I would also expect any lock-timeouts (whether specified at application layer, or at database layer) to be set appropriately for the infrastructure.

Comment: Does the log above has the strong evidence to proof that is the database problem? If yes, I will try to talk to the DBA, else DBA will throw back the problem to the application also. Btw, do you familiar with database layer configuration? If yes, can suggest what item I can configure in database layer?